# How can I edit how CiviEvent pricing is displayed?

Tags: civievent

I have a strange issue when creating a CiviEvent; which did not appear in a pre-launch test event I created but does now. As you will see below, the first fee in the list appears off-set to the rest.

[image: CiviEvent page with odd off-set]

I have checked on the dmaster site and it does not react this way. Of course it may be something that is happening on the Drupal side. I am using D7.38 and Civi4.4.14

Comment: Do you want to flip your civi pages over to using a different drupal theme and see if that makes the problem 'change' as I suspect this is a theme issue. On the Drupal Themes 'list' page ie at /admin/appearance you should be able to change the theme used for the "CiviCRM Public theme"

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to fix this with custom CSS. The following class is what you would need to adjust. Try setting the margin-left rule until the options line up. I have seen this when I am adjusting column widths on front end forms.

.crm-container .crm-section .content {
    margin-left: 17%;
}

Note: my edits are usually in WordPress. There may be interactions with your Drupal theme that override this.